# Problems with traversing dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a_list = [45, 90, 30, 33, 34, 64, 34, 28, 72, 20]

def sort_by_digit(a_list):

list_0 = []
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
list_3 = []
list_4 = []
list_5 = []
list_6 = []
list_7 = []
list_8 = []
list_9 = []


digit_dic = dict()
x = 0
for i in a_list:
    val = a_list[x] % 10

    x +=1

    if val == 0:
        list_0.append(i)

    elif val == 1:
        list_1.append(i)

    elif val == 2:
        list_2.append(i)

    elif val == 3:
        list_3.append(i)

    elif val == 4:
        list_4.append(i)

    elif val == 5:
        list_5.append(i)

    elif val == 6:
        list_6.append(i)

    elif val ==7:
        list_7.append(i)

    elif val == 8:
        list_8.append(i)

    elif val == 9:
        list_9.append(i)



if len(list_0) != 0:
    digit_dic[0] = list_0

if len(list_1) != 0:
    digit_dic[1] = list_1

if len(list_2) != 0:
    digit_dic[2] = list_2

if len(list_3) != 0:
    digit_dic[3] = list_3

if len(list_4) != 0:
    digit_dic[4] = list_4

if len(list_5) != 0:
    digit_dic[5] = list_5

if len(list_6) != 0:
    digit_dic[6] = list_6

if len(list_7) != 0:
    digit_dic[7] = list_7

if len(list_8) != 0:
    digit_dic[8] = list_8

if len(list_9) != 0:
    digit_dic[9] = list_9

print digit_dic

return digit_dic


def chart(dictionary):

   x = 0

   for i in a_list:
       if x not in dictionary:
           x += 1 
   else:
       number_of_hashes = len(dictionary[x])
       print x, number_of_hashes * '#'
       x += 1     

chart(sort_by_digit(a_list))
```

I have to write a program that sorts a random list by the last digit and puts them in a dictionary with the last digit as key. after that i have to write a program that prints length of the key value pair so for axample i would get as output

0 ###
2 #
3 #
4 ###
5 #
8 #

however i get stuck at 0 ### and i dont see what i am doing wrong and why the other output does not appear! please help, any other comments on my code are more than welcome! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.4/bin/python

import pprint
import collections

def main():
    a_list = [45, 90, 30, 33, 34, 64, 34, 28, 72, 20]
    dict_ = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for element in a_list:
        val = element % 10
        dict_[val].append(element)
    pprint.pprint(dict_)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! i runned it and it works great but it is hard for me to wrap my head around what actually is going on? could you maybe elaborate on this? thank you in advance! however i am still stuck with my output problem!

Comment: collections.defaultdict(list) is a more or less a regular dictionary, except it has default values of empty lists.  It's using list() to get an empty list internally.  Or do you have some other question(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Can i try this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

dic = dict()

lis = [45, 90, 30, 33, 34, 64, 34, 28, 72, 20]

for dig in lis:
    key = str(dig)[1]
    dic.setdefault(key, [])
    dic[key].append(dig)

for k in sorted(dic.keys()):
    print k, '#'*len(dic[k]),
```

Output:

```
0 ### 2 # 3 # 4 ### 5 # 8 #
```